# React CCSTransitionGroup animation not applying enter/leave classes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a simple page slider. Here, when I click a page, it creates a new Page with random content, and re-renders the App component. On App render(), instead of the TransitionGroup holding both state.pages until animation completes, it just switches out the pages, never attaching the enter-leave classes and not performing the css animation. I'm sure I'm messing something up in the LifeCycle, but can't think of it.

Thanks for looking!

```
var Page = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    var pgs = ['page-one','page-two','page-three','page-four']
    currentIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * pgs.length);
    var pg = pgs[ currentIdx ];
    var newPg = <Page html={pg} title={'Title for ' + pg} />;
    React.renderComponent(<App newPage={newPg} />, document.body)
  },
  render: function(){
    return (<div className="content" style={{paddingTop: 44}} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.html}</div>);
  }
})

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {pages: [<Page html="initial page" title="initial title" />]};
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setState({pages: [this.props.newPage]})
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.setState({pages: [nextProps.newPage]});
    },
  render: function() {
    var title = this.state.pages.length ? this.state.pages[ this.state.pages.length - 1 ].props.title : 'none';
    return (
      <div id="body">
        <TitleBar title={title} />
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="pg" id="transdiv" component={React.DOM.div}>
          {this.state.pages}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was setting the Page keys in Page.render() (not shown above), and not in App.render() I'm not sure why you can't set keys in the child/owned component as long as they're unique, but this fixed my problem.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    // other methods are same

    render: function(){
        var title = 'Title';
        var pgs = this.state.pages.map(function(pg){

            // SET KEY HERE
            pg.props.key = pg.props.title;
            return pg;
        }
        return (
            <div id="body">
                <TitleBar title={title} />
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="pg" id="transdiv" component={React.DOM.div}>
                    {pgs}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also, if anyone can tell me the correct way to set props on unmounted components, please tell me. Setting them directly works, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you can't set keys in the child/owned component as long as they're unique." Fundamentally, the child component can't know who its siblings are and so the parent is the one who has to pick the key. You shouldn't mutate props after a component (descriptor) is created; it's better to specify all of the props up front and mutating props like this may be disallowed in a future version of React. In your case, you probably want to store the `<Page/>` components with keys in the first place or store pure model data and create the `<Page/>` components (with keys) each time in render.